# How do I pull my app off the app store without preventing paid customers from continuing to use it?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am looking to pull my app off the app store.

How can I do it while letting paid users continue using the app?

Answer (score 1):

Simply set all the regions that you sell you app to, to none. This will remove it from the App Store. You can't remove something from a device that's not yours, for good reason. Just know that the users who do retain the app and continue using it won't have access to any bug fixes and updates, until you put it back for sell.